# can old user login into new wordpress install

Tags: wordpress, authentication, salt, wordpress-login

I have a running website on wordpress which has been hacked, some file were changed by the hacker including wp-config.php file. Now i want to install new version of wordpress, installing new wordpress means new Keys and salts. Can old user login into my new wordpress site with the same old password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he changes the `wp-congfig.php` file, then he has the access to your server by cpanel or ftp. So by changing the WordPress Username/password or re-installing WordPress will not affect the hacker. Because wp-config.php file is in the root folder, not on theme folder.

**Solution:**

Change all the passwords of cPanel and FTPs.

Once you re-installed a fresh WordPress version and using the same old wp database, then all your old WordPress users can login to your website with old username and Password.

Comment: Why?? He asked " Can old user login into my new wordpress site with the same old password?" and I answered "No" with good explanation na?

Comment: You didn't answer no, you answered "how can I secure my site after it has been hacked?"  What he wants to know if "Can all my old Wordpress users still log in once I reinstall Wordpress and hook up to my database?"

Comment: Actually he didn't clearly mentioned that is it "all my old WordPress Users" or the hacker.

Comment: I agree, it isn't the clearest question in the world. +1 now you've updated.